# Slim 3 Class not found (Controller)

Tags: php, composer-php, slim-3

I'm currently trying to get familiar with Slim 3 and just want to add a simple controller.

**Error message:**

```
Details
Type: Error
Message: Class 'app\controllers\HomeController' not found
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\slim\app\config\dependencies.php
Line: 13
```

**My project structure:**

```
\app
   \config
      routes.php
      dependencies.php
   \controllers
      HomeController.php
\public
   index.php
composer.json
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "app/"            
    }
}
```

**dependencies.php**

```
<?php
$container = $app->getContainer();

// controller
$container['HomeController'] = function($container) {
    return new app\controllers\HomeController;
};
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$app->get('/', 'HomeController:index');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class HomeController 
{
    public function index()
    { ... }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php    
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';  
require __DIR__ . '/../app/config/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);    
require __DIR__ . '/../app/config/dependencies.php';    
require __DIR__ . '/../app/config/routes.php'; 
$app->run();
```

What I tried else:

- I tried `composer dump-autoload -o` and `composer update` without luck.
- I double checked spelling mistakes in my namespace and folder structure.
- I don't use shorttags eg. `<?`

I would appreciate any suggestions from you!

Comment: I don't think you need this part: `// controller
$container['HomeController'] = function($container) {
    return new app\controllers\HomeController;
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's namespaces is case insensitive, Windows file system is case insensitive, but AFAIK composer's autoloader is not. Try with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "app\\" : "app/"            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know who this might help. So we had a similar issue.

What we did was to remove the vendor file and then reinstall the dependencies with "composer install".